Is this possible on salesforce flexi page display field labels above the field values?
Our customers would prefer Salesforce flexi page to display field labels above the field values to reduce the white space between the field label and field value.
Looks like if we squeeze the browser window, this will happen automatically, however, is this possible to have it even for broader windows?
our customers complain about a lot of wasted space on the screen

Wouldn't displaying the labels above the fields use more space?  ie. the field value would be 100% of the width (instead of 33% for the label, 67% for the value), but it would take up more vertical space because the label would be above the value?

Salesforce has a display density setting in setup. A compact setting renders labels and values side by side, a comfy setting renders labels above the values.
You can try the comfy setting, but it does not give you more space on the screen to fit more fields.
It seems you are looking for a mix of comfy and compact which is not an OOTB feature.


thanks, we can suggest this solution to our customers
